# i deployed a contract but the initialBuyTax did not change to the finalBuyTax and eth is stuck in the contract

Tags: solidity

So i deployed a contract but needed to stop the project and relaunch after i noticed it did not change initialbuytax 25 to finalbuytax 0 also it did not swap the tax and send the eth to the deployer wallet. instead its now stuck in the contract.
what did i do wrong? and how to fix?
contract https://etherscan.io/address/0x07b7bb922f04154ecc26e69685df9aa6fcbcf389#code
deployer https://etherscan.io/address/0x21c990291969b91eaee7ab1c020113810776338e

Comment: It looks like a scam contract. You shouldn't deploy and deposit ether in contract you do not understand. In any case you should test before deploying to production in a testnet if you aren't sure.